# Can't select bone in pose mode and object together

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to select a bone and an object and then go to weight paint mode, but Blender won't let me select the object when I'm in pose mode, the lock object mode in edit menu is unchecked. Why will it still not let me select one bone and the object together?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have them selected together to enable weight painting for that particular bone. To have the settings for weight-painting a certain bone's affect on an object, you must select that bone in pose mode, and then just select the object the bone is controlling. There is no need to select them at the same time, as this can not be done in pose mode.

Comment: I can not select object in pose mode ! I already said that! and the lock object mode is off!

Comment: A picture would help